# ASP .NET OpenXML : How to create password protected word file

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, openxml

```
        byte[] abc= Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("sdf");

        DocumentProtection prot = new DocumentProtection();
        prot.Edit = DocumentProtectionValues.ReadOnly;
        prot.Hash = Convert.ToBase64String(abc);
        settings1.Append(prot);
```

I have tried the above mentioned code where read only is working fine but i am facing issue with setting password using hash(#). Suggest me the possible way

Comment: i even tried

 prot.Hash =Base64BinaryValue.FromString("dsf");

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

1) In visual studio go to Project Menu -> Add Reference

2) Select "COM" tab

3) Select "Microsoft Word (version No.) Object Library"

4) Press OK.

5) Now, add reference of this library in .cs page.

E.g. `using Microsoft.Office.Interop;`

6) Create a word file object and set its password like shown below :

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document oDoc;
oDoc.Password = "abcd";
```

Please don't forget to save the document.

Thanks

Please mark and up vote if it is useful.

Comment: don't forget to save the document, close the file and kill the Word process.

Comment: @VladSpreys Spreys :) Ya. Thanks.

Comment: Please understand that this will open WORD.EXE everytime you run your application.

Comment: Don't move away from openxml to vsto interop for this little inconvenience!